# Django appeared ajax error after uploading the site to heroku

Tags: javascript, django, ajax, heroku

I am making a portfolio site in django and I wanted to upload it to heroku. Everything worked fine on localhost, but after uploading the site to heroku, I started getting errors when using AJAX.

Im using ajax for register user and sending email massage

Js

```
    $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: "",
            enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
            data: fd,
            success: function(response) {
                mess = $('.b-popup_message')
                if (response.status == 'login') {
                    window.location.href = '/';
                    mess.text('Wait...')
                }
                else {
                    mess.text('We have sent the code to you by mail. Enter it')
                }

            },
            error: function(error) {
                console.log(error);
            },
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
        })
        return false
```

view.py

```
def main(request):
global code
login_form = LoginForm(request.POST or None)
data = {}
if request.method == 'POST':
    if login_form.is_valid():
        if request.is_ajax():
            email = request.POST.get('email')

            data['email'] = email
            data['code'] = login_form.cleaned_data['code']

            if not code or code != data['code']:
                sleep(10)
                code = generate_code(4)

                send_email_message = EmailMessage('DONUTELA CODE', f'Enter this code on the register form: {code}', to=[email])

                send_email_message.send()
                data['status'] = 'sent_code'

            elif code == data['code']:
                if User.objects.filter(email=email).exists():
                    user = User.objects.get(email=email)
                else:
                    user = User.objects.create_user(username=generate_code(20), email=email, password=generate_code(20))
                login(request, user, backend='MainApp.Backends.PasswordlessAuthBackend')
                data['status'] = 'login'
            return JsonResponse(data=data)

added_products_cookies = request.COOKIES.get('added_products')

added_product_names = []  # все добавленые продукты по названию
added_products_dict = {}  # вид {название продукты: кол-во добавленых}
if added_products_cookies is not None:  # если куки не пустое ищем
    apcs = added_products_cookies.split('.')

    apcs = set(apcs)
    apcs.remove('')
    print(apcs)

    for prod in apcs:
        print(prod)
        sp = prod.split('|')
        print(sp)
        added_product_names.append(sp[0])
        added_products_dict[sp[0]] = sp[1]

# total price
total_price = 0
for name, col in added_products_dict.items():
    prod = Product.objects.get(name=name)
    print(prod.price, col)
    total_price += float(prod.price) * int(col)
total_price = round(total_price, 2)

context = {'login_form': login_form, 'total_price': total_price}
print(request.method)
return render(request, 'MainApp/main.html', context)
```

console

```
jquery-3.6.0.min.js:2 POST https://donut-ella-store.herokuapp.com/ 500 (Internal Server Error)

readyState: 4
```

responseText: "\n<!doctype html>\n<html lang="en">\n\n  Server Error (500)\n\n\n

## Server Error (500)

\n\n\n"
setRequestHeader: ƒ (e,t)
state: ƒ ()
status: 500
statusCode: ƒ (e)
statusText: "Internal Server Error"

heroku logs

```
2021-08-08T16:11:09.641476+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/" host=donut-ella-online-store.herokuapp.com request_id=3b9977a9-3237-4a45-87e0-d24209bf9982 fwd="37.112.48.196
```

" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=906ms status=500 bytes=403 protocol=https

Before I uploaded the site to heroku there were no errors. If you have any idea why this is happening or how to fix it please help

Comment: [HTTP 500](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#5xx_Server_Error) is a generic server-side error message. On its own it doesn't tell us anything useful. Any time you see this your first step should be to check your error logs for more detail. On Heroku, that usually means running `heroku logs`. Hopefully there's more information in your logs than what you're showing us. And if not, add some more logging.